# Install Windows Phone 7.1 SDK on Windows 8.1 RTM with Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

Does anyone know how to develop for Windows Phone 7, with Visual Studio 2013 (thus without installing Visual Studio 2010) on Windows 8.1 RTM?
I've checked the WP8.0 box when I was installing Visual Studio 2013, but it does not provide me the 7.1 SDK which is needed for my solution.

It would be great if I could do it without installing Visual Studio 2010. :D

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8.0 SDK include the ability to create apps for 7.1 and 8.0 so there should be no need to install the 7.1 SDK.

**HOWEVER**
Developing apps for 7.x is not supported in Visual Studio 2013.
If you must target 7.x devices you'll need to use VS2010 or VS2012.

If you want o build for Windows Phone 7.x you should use Visual Studio 2012. You can install this AND Visual Studio 2013 on the same machine. The only thing you may not end up being able to do is having a single solution with all projects in that you can use in both versions of VS.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's a shame, I will have some compatibilities problems with my solution =/

Comment: Ah, that would explain why I can't work on my WP7 app anymore. That's a shame.

Comment: Is it possible to just redownload the 7.1 SDK when using VS2013?

Comment: @Matthew installing the 7.1 SDK is not supported in VS2013

Comment: Are you sure sdk 8.0 supports apps for 7.1? I cant see it in the documentation http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Comment: Yes, WP8 SDK does support creating app for WP7.5 devices (same as with WP7.1 SDK), but that is not allowed on Visual Studio 2013. You can create and target WP7.1 apps with WP8 SDK using Visual Studio 2012. In fact, the URL you linked clearly says "The Windows Phone Software Development Kit (SDK) 8.0 provides you with the tools that you need to develop apps and games for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7.5"