# How to Target WP7.1 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have just upgraded to Windows 8.1 and installed Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to update a previous WP7.1 solution but when opening with VS2013 I am asked to update some things. I select yes, and everything seems to work except for the Windows Phone Toolkit I got from NuGet in my original solution (built in VS2012). After updating I had a migration report error saying `Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. For more information, visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages. Packages affected: WPtoolkit`. Since my app was built targeting WP7.1 in VS2012 I assumed that removing and redownloading the WPToolkit would work, but it targets WP80 by default. It seems I cannot create a Windows Phone app targeting 7.1 anymore? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You could *not* use NuGet, for starters.

Comment: Well, I made a sample application for windows phone in VS2013, but I was not asked which framework to target before the solution was made, like in VS2012. Has this been depreciated in VS2013?

Comment: Try reinstall the 7.1 SDK to see if you get the templates.

Comment: Before I do that, according to Matt Lacey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022962/install-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-on-windows-8-1-rtm-with-visual-studio-2013-rc he states `Developing apps for 7.x is not supported in Visual Studio 2013.` so it must be done in 2010 or 2012.

Comment: Well, VS2013 can open WP7.1 projects, and if you deploy to a device, I can't see the problem. It might require some manual changes to the build scripts. I can't tell about official support, I haven't seen us communicate anything out. Although staying on VS2012 is recommended.

Comment: Yes, it does open the project but it does force me to perform project updates otherwise it won't load the solution. I'm probably going to redownload VS2012, it shouldn't effect VS2013 should it?

Comment: Both works fine in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create wp7.1 apps in vs2013. It is not supported by visual studio 2013.However you can upgrade your wp7 app to wp8 app in vs2013. just open it in vs2013 and do same manual changes

Comment: Good luck, this simply isn't true. A majority of time the upgrade is plagued with errors that lead you to pretty much having to rewrite the application.

Comment: can you explain how, at the time answer was posted @Euthyphro

Comment: can you take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19024001/2641752 @downvoter

Comment: XNA was an advertised feature to developers making apps for Windows Mobile 7.1 and Visual Studio 2010. Nonetheless, soon after MS killed it and now by VS2012/13 it is completely removed. XNA is not supported in VS2013 at all. Thus trying to upgrade a Windows Mobile 7.1 app to Mobile 8 through VS2013 if it is using XNA is impossible. The only solution I could find is to rewrite the app or stick with VS2010. With that in mind, your answer is inaccurate - hence the downvote. Not all apps using 7.1 can be upgraded to 2013.

Comment: Do op refer xna anywhere in his question ? His question was about genral phone apps not Xna game apps.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Tools>Nuget Package Manager> Package Manager Console

Write the following command:

PM> Update-Package -reinstall SilverlightToolKitWP

Comment: this replies: "Update-Package : Unable to find package 'SilverlightToolKitWP'."