# Visual Studio 2015 with Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2015

I cannot find 100% answer if there is an option to develop Windws Phone 7 app using Visual Studio 2015. I am almost sure it is immposible but still not 100%.

There is nothing about Windows Phone 7 in Visual Studio 2015 specifications as below:

```
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use VS 2015 for WP7 development. You even can't use VS 2013 for that. Only VS 2010 and 2012 can be used to develop apps for WP7.

See older questions about VS 2013 and WP7 compability for additional info:

- [Install Windows Phone 7.1 SDK on Windows 8.1 RTM with Visual Studio 2013 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022962/install-windows-phone-7-1-sdk-on-windows-8-1-rtm-with-visual-studio-2013-rc)
- [How to Target WP7.1 in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759876/how-to-target-wp7-1-in-visual-studio-2013)